# how to write "and" in Regex

Tags: regex

How to write "and" in Regex. Like we can write "or" using pipe | similarly is there a way to write "and"

I have

- REGEX1 : `^(?!([0-9])\1{2}[-. ]*\1{3}[-. ]*\1{4}$)` which validates anything except numbers like 111-111-1111 or 111.111.1111 and another
- REGEX2: `^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$` which validates numbers like 784-223-4567

I want the digit string to be valid only if both REGEX1 && REGEX2 conditions are satisfied

Comment: Please give an example of what you are trying to match, and what you intend to not match.

Comment: Could you give an example of when it would be applicable? I can't even think of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **default regex standard** (as defined by *Kleene*) has no way to write *and*: it only has the concatenation, disjunction and Kleene star. You can however apply the regex engine multiple times. For instance:

```
grep "regex1" < file | grep "regex2"
```

So using a *pipe* the first `grep` filters all lines that match the first regex, and the second `grep` filters the result even deeper.

If you use an **extended version of regexes** (with positive lookahead), you can implement the *and*-pattern:

```
(?=regex1)(?=regex2)regex3
```

Perl and most other P-languages support this pattern. But most other languages don't.

**EDIT**: based on your comment, and using the second pattern, the regex reads:

```
^(?=(?!([0-9])\1{2}[-. ]*\1{3}[-. ]*\1{4}$))\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/kS2lY2/3).

Comment: I have a regex say REGEX1:  ^(?!([0-9])\1{2}[-. ]*\1{3}[-. ]*\1{4}$) which matches anything except numbers like 111-111-1111 and another regex say REGEX2:^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$ which matches numbers like 789-456-1234 
I need to ensure that a string is valid only if it satifies REGEX1 && REGEX2

Comment: @ChristineDsouza: you probably made a typo in regex2: `(?` to `(?:` (with colon)?

Comment: no there isn't any typo

Comment: @ChristineDsouza: regex101 gives an error on your second regex: https://regex101.com/r/tG3vK6/1.

Comment: my bad ^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$ dats d correct one

Comment: ders backslash before(? and after{3}) which i don't know is not being pasted out here

Comment: @ChristineDsouza: so `^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$`?

Comment: @ChristineDsouza: see updated answer, and it's "that's" and "there's" btw...

Comment: Can you help me update my Regex so that it can also validate and return no match for 5 repeated digits in a number for eg. 1234512345 or 456-784-5678?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use negations, you can do:
 
        Not( (not(a) | (not(b))

Comment: Most regex engines don't provide an `not(.)` either.

Comment: Which is why I said "if".